# What does “but” mean?

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

> As for indolence, that would be ridiculous, but there are other interesting things.

What does this mean? I'm especially interested in what the "*but*" means here.

Answer (score 4):

*But* is the ordinary conjunction here, signalling that what follows denies or qualifies what has just been said.

> Reverting to the topic of marriage: it would of course be silly for them to marry. However, men and women may enter into other sorts of firm relationship which are more interesting.

Comment: Not in this context, no.

Comment: @user4550 To disambiguate sweeneyrod's response, it is NOT possible to interpret *but* as *unless*.

Comment: I don't recall this particular passage from Dorian Gray, but given the overall context of the book, he probably does not mean other "firm" relationships, but rather that he considers a more transient, non-committal relationship to be preferable.

Comment: @Jay I think Lord Henry has a maintenance relationship in mind. This age is sort of the last gasp of the aristocrat's kept mistress: think Edward and Mrs. Lantry.  M.Hollande, to be sure, is trying to revive the tradition, but he's too much a bourgeois not to make a hash of it.

Comment: @StoneyB Well, that could be. I suppose I could actually go back and check the book to see if it's clear from context.

Comment: @user4550: 1) *That* refers to marriage, the topic to which Lord Henry is returning. 2) It's not that Hollande is too "low" class, but that the aristocratic manner he seeks to emulate is gone with the wind.

Comment: @StoneyB: It might be perverse, but I'm not 100% convinced it's "impossible" to interpret *but* as *unless* here. For example ['Now, gentle and courteous knight, give me the sword again.' 'Nay,' said Balin, 'for this sword will I keep **but it be** taken from me with force.'](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22but+it+be+taken%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Archaic, I know, but it's at least *feasible* to just "modernise" **be** to **were** (or more likely, **is/was**), but not change **but** to **unless**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In ModE & PDE idiom you can say *but **that*** = "except for the fact that" -- but that really calls for "would be" in the main clause. And to my ear the Malory use isn't even Early Modern, it's late Middle English and requires the subjunctive.

Answer (score 0):

You use the word `but` when you already told enough pleasant things to the listener and you finally decide state what really matters.